# Fast matrix update with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, file-io, matrix

My problem is, I need to read around 50M lines from a file in format

```
x1 "\t" x2 "\t" .. x10 "\t" count
```

and then to compute the matrix A with components A[j][i] = Sum (over all lines) count * x_i * x_j.

I tried 2 approaches, both reading the file line per line:

1) keep A a Python matrix and update in for loop:

```
  for j in range(size):
    for i in range(size):
      A[j][i] += x[j] * x[i] * count
```

2) make A a numpy array, and update using numpy.add:

```
  numpy.add(A, count * numpy.outer(x, x))
```

What surprised me is that the 2nd approach has been around 30% slower than the first one. And both are really slow - around 10 minutes for the whole file...

Is there some way to speed up the calculation of the matrix? Maybe there is some function that would read the data entirely from the file (or in large chunks) and not line per line? Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the "\t" tabs or is that the literal representation of what is in the file, can you read the whole file in memory?

Comment: "\t" are tabs, the entire file is 4.5 GB so that it fits to memory, although I don't know if it can speed up the calculation...

Comment: You can delay multiplying on `count` till the end `i` range calculation, since `a1*c + a2*c + ... + an*c = (a1 + a2 + ... + an) * c`

Comment: How much of the 10 minutes are spent reading the file vs processing?

Comment: Just for clarification: In your example `size` is 10, i.e. `A` is a 10x10 matrix, and you are doing those operations for each of the 50M lines? Could you show the full code?

Comment: Is it possible to 'resave' the file in a format which is quicker to load in? E.g. a `.npy` file? Of course this is only possible if you have one file which you are reading in on multiple occasions, not a different file each time.

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, that's correct. My full code is somewhat more complicated, I extracted the relevant part of it. The matrix is initialized as 10 x 10 matrix of zeros.

Comment: @Bill Cheatham Basically, the whole procedure is just needed once for each file, so that saving the file in other format won't help much I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

- Use [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) with the `C` engine to read the file. It is a lot faster than np.genfromtxt because the engine is c/Cython optimized.
- You can read the whole file in memory and then do the calculations. this is the easiest way but from an efficiency perspective your CPU will be mostly idle waiting for input. This time could be better used calculating stuff.
- You can try to read and process line by line (ex: with the cvs module). While io will still be the bottleneck by the end you will have processed your file. The problem here is that you still will have some efficiency loss due to the Python overhead.
- Probably the best combination would be to read by chunks using `pandas.read_csv` with the `iterator` and `chunk_size` parameters set and process chunks at a time. I bet there is an optimal chunk size that will beat the other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix is symmetric, compute just the upper half using your first approach (55 computations per row instead of 100).

The second approach is slower. I don't know why but, if you're instantiating 50M small ndarrays, it is possible that's the bottleneck and possibly using a single ndarray and copying each row data

```
x = np.zeros((11,))
for l in data.readlines():
    x[:] = l.split()
    A+=np.outer(x[:-1],x[:-1])*x[-1]
```

may result in a speedup.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much memory you have available on you machine, you try using a regular expression to parse the values and numpy reshaping and slicing to apply the calculations. If you run out of memory, consider a similar approach but read the file in, say, 1M line chunks.

```
txt = open("C:/temp/input.dat").read()
values = re.split("[\t|\n]", txt.strip())

thefloats = [ float(x) for x in values]
mat = np.reshape(thefloats, (num_cols, num_rows))

for i in range(len(counts)):
    mat[:-1,i] *= counts[-1,i]
```